# Runtime exception while parsing date in linux system (Working fine in windows system)

Tags: java, unix, jodatime

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

final java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter =
         java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

final LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse("Fri Sep 14 18:04:03 BST 2018", formatter)
```

The above code is working fine in Windows system but in Linux system its throwing Runtime exception :
 `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`: Text 'Fri Sep 14 18:16:13 BST 2018' could not be parsed: null

Comment: Can't reproduce (on Linux)

Comment: The code works fine on my Linux system.

Comment: What time zone is `BST` supposed to be? [British Summer Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst)? [Bangladesh Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst-bangladesh)? [Bougainville Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst-bougainville)? --- This is likely the reason the parsing fails, and depends on the installed version of Java.

Comment: check timezone on both systems? might be problem with timezone.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer but 1 thing I updated wrongly is that before parsing the date I was doing new Date().toString() which might have caused issue I believe. Now I have changed the code to this but still having same issue:

private String getCurrentDate() 
 {
       SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
       return format.format(new Date());
 }
final LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(getCurrentDate() , formatter)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely because your Linux system is using a non-English Locale, i.e. Friday is not named `Fri`.

Explicitly specify the locale:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.UK);
```